# if statement and mutate

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

```
EMPLTOT_N   FIRMTOT average min
12289593    4511051 5   1
26841282    1074459 55  10
15867437    81243   300 100
6060684 8761    750 500
52366969    8910    1000    1000
137003  47573   5   1
226987  10372   55  10
81011   507 300 100
23379   52  750 500
13698   42  1000    1000
67014   20397   5   1
```

My data look like the data above. I want to create a new column EMP using mutate function that:

```
emp= average*FIRMTOT if EMPLTOT_N/FIRMTOT<min
and emp=EMPLTOT_N if EMPLTOT_N/FIRMTOT>min
```

Answer (score 0):

In your sample data `EMPLTOT_N / FIRMTOT` is never less than `min`, but this should work:

```
df <- read.table(text = "EMPLTOT_N   FIRMTOT average min
12289593    4511051 5   1
26841282    1074459 55  10
15867437    81243   300 100
6060684 8761    750 500
52366969    8910    1000    1000
137003  47573   5   1
226987  10372   55  10
81011   507 300 100
23379   52  750 500
13698   42  1000    1000
67014   20397   5   1", header = TRUE)

library('dplyr')
mutate(df, emp = ifelse(EMPLTOT_N / FIRMTOT < min, average * FIRMTOT, EMPLTOT_N))
```

In the above if `EMPLTOT_N / FIRMTOT == min`, `emp` will be given the value of `EMPLTOT_N` since you didn't specify what you want to happen in this case.

Comment: The caveat at the beginning of your answer makes no sense. If the ratio is never less than 'min' then only the second vector would get assigned to 'emp' so there would be no point to this operation.

Comment: @BondedDust Based on the OP's question I am assuming the actual data does contain rows where the ratio is less than `min` and that this just wasn't reflected in the sample they provided. If this isn't the case then yes, the `ifelse()` is obviously pointless.